# If not found assign value

Tags: python

I am pulling data out of a file that looks like this 
"LIC_ARP11|104100000X|33"
I collect the taxonomy number (taxonomies) out of the second field and translate it using another file (IDVtaxo) that looks like this:

"104100000X      Behavioral Health & Social Service Providers    Social Worker"

If the taxonomy number is not in IDVtaxo I want to append "Not Found"

```
if taxofile.startswith('IDV'):
    for nums in taxonomies:
            IDVfile = open (os.path.join(taxodir,IDVtaxo))
            for line in IDVfile:
                    text = line.rstrip('\n')
                    text = text.split("\t")
                    if nums in line:
                            data = text[2:]
                            final.append(data)
                    else:
                            final.append('Not Found')
```

Then I print the original data along with the translated taxonomy. Currently I get:
"LIC_ARP11|104100000X|33| Not Found"
I want:
"LIC_ARP11|104100000X|33 | Social Worker"

The issue seems to be that the "else" appends "Not Found" for each line instead of just when the taxonomy isn't found in IDVtaxo.

---

```
taxonomies = ['152W00000X', '156FX1800X', '200000000X', '261QD0000X', '3336C0003X', '333600000X', '261QD0000X']
translations = {'261QD0000X': 'Clinic/Center   Dental', '3336C0003X': 'Pharmacy        Community/Retail Pharmacy',  '333600000X': 'Pharmacy'}
a = 0
final = []


for nums in taxonomies:
    final.append(translations.get(nums, 'Not Found'))

for nums in taxonomies:
    print nums, "|", final[a]
    a = a + 1
```

Comment: The comparison operator is `==` not `=`

Comment: you also never define `text`

Comment: Why do people upvote questions like this? Just VTC as a typo and move on...

Comment: This is a very inefficient way to do what you want, also setting `found = False` might be a better idea.  What does `IDVtaxo` look like?

Comment: I was trying to only posted the problematic part.

IDVTaxo has lines like this:

372500000X      Nursing Service Related Providers       Chore Provider

Comment: @user3670277,  so the number is the first element from each line? This can probably be done quite easily in  in `O(n)` time, your code is quadratic

Comment: Yes. I want everything beyond the generic type data, hence the [2:]

Comment: so what do the numbers in `taxonomies` look like?  Is `372500000X` a potential number even with the X?

Comment: ['152W00000X', '156FX1800X', '200000000X', '261QD0000X', '3336C0003X', '261QD0000X', '333600000X']

Comment: I deleted my answer as I have no idea what you are asking, I suggest you ask a new question and stop editing this one, when you ask the question supply some input and expected output

Answer (score 3):

equality operator in Python is `==`:

```
>>> if data == 'Not Found':
...     final.append(data)
```

for "not equal":

```
>>> if data != 'Not Found':
...     final.append(data)
```

Comment: Tried and it still doesn't work. I get "Not Found" for everything.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are testing for presence of `nums` in each line, appending 'Not Found' **every time** you fail to find `nums`.

Instead, try maintaining a variable (e.g. `job_title`) storing 'Not Found' string. If `nums` is found, reassign `job_title` to correct value and append it to `final` outside of the loop.

I believe you can get a more efficient solution if you load IDVtaxo into a dictionary structure! https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries